# Can two mosfets (p&n, some characteristics) be used as current sources simultaneously? And what happens if the Vgs voltage change?

Tags: transistors, current, mosfet

Can two mosfets (p and n type with some characteristics) be used as current sources simultaneously? And what happens if the Vgs voltage change in just one of them? [image]

Comment: Take a step back, replace both MOSFETs with a current source and think about what happens, if one current is larger than the other, or if both currents are equal.

Comment: You really should wait a while before accepting any answer.  Once a question has a accepted answer, others are likely to just skip it.  You'll then never know what someone else might have said.  I good guide is to wait 24 hours or until at least 3 answers are posted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done.  It can even be useful in some cases, although not usually with the load where you show it.

Let's consider your circuit without Rload, just the two transistors connected together directly.  We'll consider this node the output.

If the two current sources were ideal and exactly matched, then the output voltage could be anywhere between the supply rails.  If one of the sources was set to even a little higher current than the other, that source would have low voltage across it and the other with maximum voltage across it.

If you arranged the input signal to vary the two current sources oppositely, then you would ideally have a infinite gain amplifier.  When the input is at one side of the threshold, the output slams one way.  When at the other side, the output slams the other way.

Real current sources, such as implemented by these transistors, do not have ideal infinite impedance, or course.  Put another way, their current is at least some small function of the output voltage.  In that case, if the two were exactly matched, the output voltage would be in the middle.  The mismatch in the current setting of the two sources would create a output voltage offset from the middle.  This output mismatch voltage would be the mismatch current times the parallel impedance of the two sources.

The result can still be a very high voltage gain.  If designed for this application and operated in the right region, the MOSFETs will look like current sources with reasonably high impedance.  Small changes in gate voltage can have significant effect on the current.  Together, these two effects cause a large gain.

A large negative voltage gain isn't the only purpose of such a circuit, but it is one example of how such a configuration can be useful.

For discrete designs, BJTs are usually better for this.  The current thru the collector is rather independent of collector voltage over a wide operating range.  However, if this is in a IC, then a mix of BJT and MOSFET is usually not available.  The characteristics of individual transistors can also be better controlled and better matched between two devices, so the circuit you show can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Biasing such a pair of N and P MOSfets in your circuit could be difficult, and would likely require considerable DC feedback to establish a stable operating point for use as a linear amplifier. Where the two drains are connected directly (with no intervening resistor) biasing is easier - a transformer-connected load would be another simpler biasing case.
 To consider the equivalent Norton resistance of the two N & P current sources, the image below might be useful.
[image: N & P MOSfet curves]This curve was drawn as a mirror image. In practice, the N and P Mosfets will most likely have skewed characteristics, and their drain currents would not meet neatly in the middle, but it is useful to imagine the Norton resistances.
Norton resistance is the slope of the curves at the DC bias point. A load line (green) actually crosses two points on the curve (one for Nch, and one for Pch), each having a potentially different Norton resistance. For small drain currents, both curves are flat near one-half Vdd, and Norton resistance is quite large - voltage gain here would be very high, as Olin has pointed out. For larger drain currents, Norton resistance is lower, since the curves do not approach horizontal at any point (the centre point of inflection is an anomaly). Manipulating the green load line is awkward, since the point of inflection need not be at the 5v midpoint nor at ID=0, but your circuit does force \$ID_n = ID_p \$. Another constraint is \$VDS_n + VSD_p + V_{RL} = 10v\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO7Qkg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
For your circuit, the small-signal MOSfet drain connections look like a college quiz on superposition. \$RN_{mos}\$ and \$RP_{mos}\$ are the resistances at the two load-line crossing points. Switching from Norton to its Thevenin equivalent makes the solution easier, resulting in three series resistors.